# Does the listed gauge on a crimp cap take into account that two wires would go in the same end?

Tags: electrical, wiring, data-wiring, audio

What size of crimp cap be used for 16 AWG wire? I could use [butt splice of size 22-18 AWG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008LMEF0A) but prefer crimp cap connector where both wires go in the same end (so double the diameter). Should I buy [Crimp Cap 16/14 Gauge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000SBLM1C) or [Crimp Cap 12/10 Gauge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JT09FM). Does the listed gauge take into account that two wires would go in the same end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Comment converted to answer`**

A 16/14 cap should take between 1 and 4 #16 wires, but it depends on the cap. Specific information should be available on the packaging, or from the manufacturer.